# How to print out a backslash in LaTeX

Tags: file-io, latex, backslash

I want to write a backslash character to a text file using LaTeX.

The first line of code below declares a variable 'file' which describes the file 'myfile.out'. The second line opens the file and the third one tries do write a backslash '\' to the file.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
   \newwrite\file%
   \immediate\openout\file=myfile.out%
   \immediate\write\file{\}%
\end{document}
```

The third line does not work because LaTeX get confused with the backslash, anyone knows how can I make it work? I tried a lot of things including `\textbackslash, $\backslash$ \char` ``\`  etc and nothing seems to work.

Thanks a lot

Comment: I had the same problem. There are working answers on http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7359/how-to-make-a-real-backslash-escape-character

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `\@backslashchar`.  The following works for me:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\newwrite\file
\immediate\openout\file=myfile.out
\makeatletter
\immediate\write\file{\@backslashchar}
\makeatother
\closeout\file
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does not work for me. This is what is written in the text file in place of the backslash: `\spacefactor \@m {}backslashchar`

Comment: Seems to work for me - but I am not a LaTeX expert, so I am not sure how to help.  I ran "pdflatex <file.tex>".

Answer (score 22):

Sound like you want a backslash in text mode; since `\backslash` does not work, try `\textbackslash`.

EDIT: `\symbol{92}` should also work.

Comment: \textbackslash gives weird error: TeX capacity exceeded, sorry

Comment: Using \symbol{92}, I get a myfile.out which contains '\char 92\relax ' seems like it misses an expansion or something.

Comment: Maybe there are some issues with writing to text files that I'm unfamiliar with -- didn't expect this to give an error.

Comment: I'm surprised this doesn't work, as well.  Explanation, anyone?

Comment: A tentative explanation is that I think that \symbol{92} is a macro that translates to \char`92, which asks to the compiler's backend to insert the character with given number in the current font. As there is no backend when writing to files, the \char`92 macro remains unexpanded in the output.

Comment: In my overleaf document, even though `\textbackslash` didn't work, `\symbol{92}` solved the problem! Thanks @Martijn

Answer (score -1):

"AB/FQS/ET004/2014" write it in latex with space as "AB/ FQS/ ET004/ 2014"

Comment: Don't know which question this answers, but certainly not the question asked at the top.